# Is it possible to change an object's type from inside itself

Tags: c#, .net, types, casting

I have a shape class with square and triangle as inheriting classes

```
Square square = new Square();
square.SideCount = 4;
//Logic
square.SideCount = 3;
 
if(square is Triangle)
   {
   //...
```

If I instantiate a new square with SideCount = 4, then if I change it's SideCount to 3, can I put code into the SideCount's Setter to convert Square to Triangle if sides are set to 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not directly no, an instance of `Square` cannot be changed to an instance of `Triangle`.

You could have a method, which returns an instance of `Shape` defined on the base class Shape:

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public Shape Mutate(int numberOfSides)
    {
        // over simplified example:
        if(numberOfSides == 3)
           return new Triangle();
    }
}

public class Triangle : Shape {}
public class Square : Shape {}
```

usage

```
var squ = new Square();
var triangle = squ.Mutate(3);
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I was just trying to avoid having to do this outside of the class itself as I would be calling often and the conversion only relies on the property.
even if it's not the answer I wanted, Thankyou!

Comment: but the var triangle will still be a instance of Square class!

Comment: @AppDeveloper - Not if Mutate returns an instance of `Triangle` when passed `3`!

Answer (score 1):

Now, you can't. Types are rigid respect to their instance content.

In `C++` you can have generic type parametrized by integer value.

Generally, if you want to change something at runtime, you should not make it belonging to a type. So, don't make `SideCount` writable. Let user create new instance if he want another value for this property.